# does one year schengen visa automatically give the power to stay in the zone 90 days per 6 months?

Tags: schengen-visas

I have been grant a one year multiple entry visa from Dec til next year Dec.
Is that mean I stay up to 90 days til May then from June another 90 days?
Or will they mark some words on the sticker? Because seems French did

Comment: "power to stay": no. Visa is not an authorization to entry. You see it as a "pre-check". Also the reason for the visa must be valid. Often entry is granted with a visa and reasons are pretty generic, but it is not "automatic" (as your question). If there is suspect you do not have funds, you will work, you are forced in, etc, you may be denied or with a shorten period.

Comment: What has been entered in the 'duration of stay' field of the visa?

Comment: hi it is 90 days

Answer (score 1):

Type C Schengen visas are always subject to the "90/180" rule (in addition to other constraints of the visa like validity, duration...).

In **any** 180-day period, you can only stay 90 days in the Schengen Area. Any day you have been in the Schengen Area, even for a single minute, counts as a full day (so your arrival and departure days are both counted).

So you can for instance stay 90 days, stay out 90 days, stay 90 more days, stay out 90 days.

But you can't, for instance, stay the last 90 days of the first 6-month period, and the first 90 days of the second 6-month period, as that would make 180 consecutive days (even if you exit and re-enter Schengen).

As soon as you stay 90 days in a row, you need to stay out for at least 90 days. If you stay 60 days, then within the next 120 days (about 4 months), you can only stay 30 days. And so on.

The 90/180 rule is not reset by a new visa, so you can't either stay the last 90 days of your visa and the first 90 days of the next visa if you get one.

Also remember that on each stay you need to abide by the visa rules, on purpose, return, funds, insurance, etc. A visa never guarantees entry.

Comment: So if I want to make another two months summer trip  in the zone I don't have to wait til May or June as I left the zone Dec 31st?

Comment: @kyle If you stay 31 days from 1st of December to 31st of December, you an stay up to 59 more days in the period from 1st of January to May 29th. If those 59 days are at the end of that period (April 1st to May 29th) then, as the first few days from December "exit" the 180-day window, you can actually stay until June 29th. So if you just want to take one other single trip, if it's 59 days or less you can do it at any time, if it's between 60 and 90 days you need to wait April 1st.

Comment: @kyle The rule is simple but it can be difficult to figure if you're respecting it in situations with multiple trips. The best option is to use a calculator. The official one is [here](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en). Others may be more convenient.

Comment: @kyle Also remember that all durations are counted in days, not months. 3 months can be anywhere between 89 and 92 days, so really use exact dates.

Comment: Unless the 'duration of stay' field contains anything less than 90.